# How to create mapper function for a thunk in Java

Tags: java, functional-programming

I cant get this map method right. I need to specify the generic `Think<R>` but where?

```java
public class Think<T> implements Supplier<T> {

  private Supplier<T> supplier;

  public Think(Supplier<T> expression) {
    this.supplier = () -> evaluate(expression);
  }

  public static <T> Think<T> of(T value) {
    return new Think<>(() -> value);
  }

  private synchronized T evaluate(Supplier<T> expression) {
    this.supplier = expression;
    return this.supplier.get();
  }

  @Override
  public T get() {
    return this.supplier.get();
  }

  public <R> Think<R> map(Function<? super T, ? extends R> mapper) {
    return Think.of(() -> mapper.apply(get()));
  }
```

yields

`incompatible types: cannot infer type-variable(s) T (argument mismatch; R is not a functional interface)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method map itself is correct, but the problem arises when you call Think.of().

Change Think.of() method to accept a Supplier instead of a direct value of type R.

```
public static <T> Think<T> of(Supplier<T> supplier) {
    return new Think<>(supplier);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain what you intended but I would suggest something like this.  Since you have the method `of`, you may want to make the constructor private.

```
Think<Integer> t = Think.of(20);
System.out.println(t.get());
Think<String> r = t.map("foo"+t.get());
System.out.println(r.get());
```

prints

```
20
foo20
```

Modifications

```
public class Think<T> implements Supplier<T> {

  private Supplier<T> supplier;

  private Think(Supplier<T> expression) {
    this.supplier = expression.get();
  }

  public static <T> Think<T> of(T value) {
    return new Think<>(() -> value);
  }

  public <R> Think<R> map(Function<? super T, ? extends R> mapper) {
    return Think.of(mapper.apply(get()));
  }
}
```

Why do you have the evaluate method? Since it is declared private it must be for internal use only. The only place you use it is in the constructor which does nothing with the returned value of the method.

Comment: Thanks I don't want to get too much into the context as its mostly a learning exercise., There aren't many map() methods to learn from. I could only find Stream and Optional. The issue was with the of method since it wraps the result of the Supplier not the Supplier itself

Comment: @caduceus Interesting.  I thought the `of` was correct and the mapper was wrong.  When I made the change, it worked as I thought it should.  But at least you have your answer.